# combinatorics: Calculating number of different possibilities

Tags: combinatorics

This is a HW question

Part a) A normal pizza can have upto 3 toppings out of possible 18 choices, or can be one of four speciality pizzas. Calculate the number of different pizzas possible (incliding the pizza with no toppings).

I came to the conclusion that it should be $4+ \big(19 C 3\big) $ the reason I wrote 19 is because the 19th topping is "none". Is this right ?

Part b) A  4-for-all pizza consists of any four pizzas from part a arranged in a box. Calculate the total number of 4-for-all pizzas. Keep in mind that the four pizzas could be all different , or three different kinds of pizzas, or two different kinds of pizzas, or the four could be all the same. The ordering of the pizzas in the box does no matter.

For this I believe it is to do with combination with repetition. So for PArt a) I got $969$ and therefore Part b) I get $ \big((969+4-1)C4\big) $. Am I right ?

If I am wrong somewhere please provide a hint.

Comment: (1) Some ambiguity, can one have double chocolate plus anchovy? (2) The $19$-th virtual topping is ingenious, but only takes care of $3$-topping and $2$ topping pizzas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the $(19C3)$ term isn't quite right.

"Up to three toppings" means *exactly* zero of the 18, *exactly* one of the 18, *exactly* two of the 18, or *exactly* three of the 18.  This means you have $(18 C 0) + (18C1) + (18C2) + (18C3)$ options (plus the additional 4 specialty pizzas).

Also, for the record, there's a "homework" tag that usually goes with homework questions.

Comment: thanks @LevDub, are the steps in PArt b are correct as long as I have the correct value from part a.

Comment: @KjTada: Yes, when you get the correct number $N$ for the first part, the answer to the second part is $\binom{N+3}{4}$.